# Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields variables not rendering

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using a plugin called Pay for Post with Woocommerce, it hides posts or parts of posts and allows you to sell access to that post with a woocommerce product. The plugin author sent me this script that I can use to create page templates:

```
<?php
if(Woocommerce_Pay_Per_Post_Helper::is_protected()){
   //Page is protected
   if(Woocommerce_Pay_Per_Post_Helper::has_access()){
      // Do what you want to do if they have access to the page
   } else {
      // the page is protected and the user does NOT have access
      echo Woocommerce_Pay_Per_Post_Helper::get_no_access_content();
   }

} else {
   //Page is not protected do what you need to do.
}
```

I am trying to create custom versions of the page depending on if the product has been purchased or not, but I am having trouble with getting my Advanced Custom Fields variables to render properly within my page template. Here is what I have created for test purposes.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>



<?php
$video_screenshot = the_field("video_screenshot");
$video_link = the_field("video_link");
    if(Woocommerce_Pay_Per_Post_Helper::is_protected()){
    //Page is protected
        if(Woocommerce_Pay_Per_Post_Helper::has_access()){
            // Do what you want to do if they have access to the page
            echo '<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-12"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="{$video_link}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div></div>';
        } else {
            // the page is protected and the user does NOT have access
            echo Woocommerce_Pay_Per_Post_Helper::get_no_access_content();

            echo '<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-12"><img src="{$video_screenshot}" /></div></div></div>';
        }

    } else {
    //Page is not protected do what you need to do.
    } 
?>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

In the example above, when I look at a page that has not been purchased it should render a link with the source being generated from the post custom field, but it just prints the value that is inside the string:

```
<img src="{$video_screenshot}">
```

I have tried this so many ways, but I can not nail down how to include these variables in the string and have them print as they should. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have to tried to `var_dump($video_screenshot)` to see what it's holding?

Comment: @JoelHager I know it's outputting the correct info to the variable because for some reason it's also outputting that variable to the page as a string, before rendering the html. I'm assuming from me defining the variables, but I don't know why. Was hoping that the fix for this issue would address both

Comment: Don't you need to `echo` the variable?

Comment: instead of echoing the whole div, try writing the div out as plain HTML, and then using <?php echo $video_screenshot ?> inside the img tag, much like @JoelHager suggested.

Comment: I am new to php, I am not sure how to accomplish that within this setup where you are already within the php tags

Comment: @syedmh I would love to do that but I am unsure how to do that when I am within the php tags

Comment: syedmh beat me to it. Use his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can refactor your code slightly to echo the variable out in a more readable way:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    if(Woocommerce_Pay_Per_Post_Helper::is_protected()){

    //Page is protected

        if(Woocommerce_Pay_Per_Post_Helper::has_access()){

            // Do what you want to do if they have access to the page ?>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo the_field("video_link"); ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 

        <?php } else {

            // the page is protected and the user does NOT have access

            echo Woocommerce_Pay_Per_Post_Helper::get_no_access_content(); ?>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <img src="<?php echo the_field("video_screenshot") ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php }

    } else {

    //Page is not protected do what you need to do.

    } 

endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Comment: if you edit this answer to take out the variables and just use the ACF fields inside the echo statements it will match what I did to make it work. and I'll mark it as the correct answer.